# How to get the real font name via it's id number extracted from PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat

I tried to get the name of the font used in current PDF via `strings target.pdf| grep FontName`, and the output is as follows, which is the same as checking from Acrobat (Properties -> Fonts):

> << /Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /XZRPWV+font00000000217a1118 /Flags 4 /FontBBox
>
> << /Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /MVVKIG+font00000000217a1118 /Flags 4 /FontBBox
>
> << /Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /MLKZXP+font00000000217a1118 /Flags 4 /FontBBox

Any idea how I could match the font with unknown-id-number (font00000000217a1118) to a real font name, so I could install it on Mac. Thanks.

Comment: You might be better off using a graphical font-matching service...

Comment: If the fonts are embedded, look for FontFile, FontFile2 or FontFile3 entries, you could extract that and possibly open in a font library and see if there is an additional font name information in the embedded name.